# South Africa visitor visa - How long is it valid?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, south-africa, visa-expiration

What is the expiry date on South African visitor visa? I want to get a 3 month Visitor visa but not sure exactly when to use it. For example if I get the visa in May, can I use it to enter South Africa in say September and stay 3 months?(September, October, November).

Answer (score 1):

From [vfsglobal](https://www.vfsglobal.com/southafrica/newzealand/how-to-apply.html)'s South Africa page on how to apply, including the duration and when to apply :

> When to apply - For Short-Stay visas less than 3 months you should
>   apply if your travel date to South Africa falls in the next 90 days..
>   For Long-Stay visas more than 3 months you should apply no more than 9
>   weeks in advance of your intended travel date. For more information
>   please check the processing time section of your chosen category of
>   visa.